# Getting Key from datastore (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

How can I get the `Key` from a model I just inserted with `put()`?
I'm talking about the value from the `Key` column from this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT7hQ.png

Also, what is exactly `Key`? IIRC it's something that GAE generates automatically, but how/why/what for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said if you are using ndb, or db, 
however in both cases the key is a property of the entity.  Prior to the put it may be incomplete, in addition with ndb with key is the returned value of the put() call

```
key = myobj.put()

# if you are using ndb you can get the key with
myobj.key

# if db use 
myobj.key()
```

I suggest you also have a read of the docs on keys - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities

Comment: Oh, ok. I got it. I was looking for ```myobj.key.urlsafe()```. Thank you!